# Garry's mod prop location

Tags: garrys-mod

I just got Garry's mod yesterday, and as I am an avid developer, have decided to delve into the code (however, I won't go into that here.) I want to create my own props/edit the existing props, but I can't find them! I've looked everywhere. I have GCFEditor, but I will can't find the file. Could someone please help me find the file path of the props/other objects? Thank you.

PS: It starts with C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Garry's Mod\

Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

You can't find them because Garry's mod uses the props and textures from other games like Counter-Strike:Source.
Look in these files and you will find everything you need.

Comment: +1 because true, but gmod will work with some hl2 props even if you don't have hl2.